# Ltree query performance optimization of Postgres RDS DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-performance

I have a AWS RDS m5.large Postgres 10.13 database that performs a lot of the following queries

`SELECT "bundles".* FROM "bundles" WHERE "bundles"."version_id" = $1 AND (tree_path ~ ?) LIMIT $2`

Here the table structure (roughly 1M rows):

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."bundles" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('bundles_id_seq'::regclass),
    "cached_name" varchar NOT NULL,
    "uuid" uuid NOT NULL,
    "typology" int4 NOT NULL,
    "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "resource_template_id" int8,
    "state" varchar,
    "resource_id" int8,
    "version_id" int4,
    "tree_path" ltree NOT NULL,
    "tree_ordinal" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_a0e6c8e3c8" FOREIGN KEY ("resource_template_id") REFERENCES "public"."resource_templates"("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_02b50dac11" FOREIGN KEY ("resource_id") REFERENCES "public"."bundles"("id"),
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I have the following indexes (I created the version_id index after @nbk suggestion)

| INDEX NAME | ALGO | UNIQUE | COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| index_tree_paths_on_bundles_using_gist | GIST | f | tree_path |
| index_bundles_on_tree_path | BTREE | t | tree_path |
| index_bundles_on_resource_template_id | BTREE | f | resource_template_id |
| index_bundles_on_resource_id | BTREE | f | resource_id |
| bundles_version_id_idx | BTREE | f | version_id |
| bundles_pkey | BTREE | t | id |

the problem is the poor performance of the overall system. Via advanced monitoring we see a very high value for current activity:

[image]

and it seems that the forementioned query have some sort of impact on the load by waits [image]

What do you suggest to check? I'm not a DBA so I can't judge if those queries are efficent.

EDIT: as requested, here is the explain query ->

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  "bundles".* FROM "bundles" WHERE "bundles"."version_id" = 1641 AND (tree_path ~ '*{1}') LIMIT 1;
Limit  (cost=0.41..698.44 rows=1 width=225)
  ->  Index Scan using index_tree_paths_on_bundles_using_gist on bundles  (cost=0.41..4188.57 rows=6 width=225)
"        Index Cond: (tree_path ~ '*{1}'::lquery)"
        Filter: (version_id = 1641)
```

Comment: please take a look at https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions and add more information about yout tables and queries

Comment: @nbk edited, thanks

Comment: Please add also an explain and analyse of your query

Comment: @nbk added explain

Comment: not only for the slow also for the fast queries. But on the first glance you need for the first query a index on version and treepath, for the rest you will see it diesn't make a full san so they are faster, but tith the index you will get better results

Comment: @nbk updated with a list of the indexes that are active on this table

Comment: ok, but your qiezy has two parameters so use a **combined** index

Comment: @nbk slightly better but not so much